# Using Collections and HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have the following class, its fairly simple, all i am doing is storing the variables from a URL.

```
class RM {

    private String identifier, visible;

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(String visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    public RM (String identifier, //1
                String visible; {
        this.identifier = identifier;  //1
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return identifier + "\t" + visible + "\t";
    }
}
```

This is stored in a collection `List` when i pass through the variables.

```
Collection<RM> attributes1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then obtain the variables stored in the identifier field and store them in an array like below:

```
      Object rowDataprelim1 [] = new Object[1];
      RM rm = null;
      Iterator<RM> iterator = attributes1.iterator();

      while(iterator.hasNext()) {

          rm = iterator.next();
          rowDataprelim1[0] = rm.identifier;
          System.out.println(rm.identifier);
```

I then create a `HashMap`, the reason for doing so is because i want unique entries only.

```
Map<Object, Integer> numberMapping = new HashMap<>();//create a new hashmap
```

And also create an array of which i store identifier into `rowData[0]`.

```
    Object rowData[] = new Object[2];
    Iterator it = numberMapping.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        rowData[0] = attributes1.get((int) pair.getValue()).identifier;
        it.remove();
    }
```

What i cant get right is the syntax to get the value of identifier from my collections list, i believe the syntax i have used is for an `Arraylist`.

```
rowData[0] = attributes1.get((int)pair.getValue()).identifier;
```

Can someone advise the correct syntax, i only want to get identifier and not the visible. I in fact have around 30 items in my class and only want to get 12 of them for the first section of my project. I have never used collection before and i have been told to use `Collection` and not `ArrayList`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: and here the [API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html) and [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with all available methods explained there (look for `get()` or so). Also have a look at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html), in this case mainly [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger apologies i fixed this

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger get doesnt work

Comment: It would probably help to share more of your code (e.g. full methods), rather than only isolated snippets and describing how they interact.

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't give much to go on - what exactly did you try, and what behavior did you see that leads you to believe it doesn't work? `get()` is certainly the correct way to retrieve an element from a list or a value from a map. Unless you share what you tried we can't help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @dimo414 it doesn appear to work because Collection<RM> attributes1=new ArrayList<>(); its a Collection. if this were ArrayList<RM> attributes1=new ArrayList<>() then this would work

Comment: So why not change it to that? If you need a list, why constrain yourself to a collection?

Comment: @dimo414 Yes that is what i said, but ive been told to do it this way, unfortunately.

Comment: @dimo414 i am not familiar with collections which is why i am asking for help

Comment: And we're happy to help, but you need to share more specifics in order for us to help you effectively. If you have additional constraints like "use `Collection`, not `List`" it's worth mentioning that in your question. You can edit your question to add more details, code snippets, and error messages. That will help you get a better answer.

Comment: @dimo414 I have updated my question

Comment: How are you storing the `RM` class objects in the `java.util.List` collection?

Comment: You should try compiling the `RM` class first. Next, create `RM` class objects and add them to the `List` collection. Presently, the `RM` class code doesn't compile. After that you can try the next steps - one at a time.

Comment: `Collection` doesn't have a `get()` method and can't be indexed. Use the `List` interface instead.

Comment: Just note that `ArrayList` also implements `Collection`, that is, it is a `Collection`. And I can't see any reason to use `Collection`, maybe the the mystery one that told you to use `Collection` meant to use the `List` interface to declare the variable instead of the `ArrayList` (at the end you are still using `ArrayList`). Anyway if you were told to use `Collection` for that you should ask the one why this restriction. Obviously this class is also documented and you will find (as I just did) methods like `iterator()`, `stream()` and even `toArray()` to get values from it.